# How to combine two function's for file deletion

Tags: c#, string, text, text-files, csv

I have two different function to handle two different types of my input text file. One text file with double quotes and one without double quotes.

I wanted to know how can i combine these two functions to a common single function where i can handle in a more efficient way

Code:

```
//this the function to handle text file without double quotes
public void stack1()
    {
        string old;
        string iniPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\list.ini";
        bool isDeleteSectionFound = false;
        List<string> deleteCodeList = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(iniPath))
        {
            while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    isDeleteSectionFound = true;
                }
                if (isDeleteSectionFound && !old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    deleteCodeList.Add(old.Trim());
                }
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var value = line.Split('\t');
                bool deleteLine = value.Any(v => deleteCodeList.Any(w => v.Equals(w)));
                if (!deleteLine)
                {
                    sb.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, sb.ToString());
        //return;
    }

     //this the function to handle text file with double quotes
    public void stack()
    {
        string old;
        string iniPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\list.ini";
        bool isDeleteSectionFound = false;
        List<string> deleteCodeList = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(iniPath))
        {
            while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    isDeleteSectionFound = true;
                }
                if (isDeleteSectionFound && !old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    deleteCodeList.Add(old.Trim());
                }
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split('\t').Select(v => v.Trim(' ', '"'));
                bool deleteLines = values.Any(v => deleteCodeList.Any(w => v.Equals(w)));
                if (!deleteLines)
                {
                    sb.Append(line + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, sb.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("finish");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between these two functions is this line:

```
// stack1 function
var value = line.Split('\t');

// stack2 function
var values = line.Split('\t').Select(v => v.Trim(' ', '"'));
```

The simplest way would probably be to add a parameter to your method, and then add the check after the split:

```
public void Split(bool shouldTrimQuotes)
{
     ...

     IEnumerable<string> value = line.Split('\t');         
     if (shouldTrimQuotes)
     {
         value = value.Select(v => v.Trim(' ', '"'));
     }

     ...
}
```

In one case, you would pass `true` as the parameter (which will cause quotes to be trimmed), while in the second one you would pass `false` to indicate you don't want to trim them:

```
// split, but don't trim quotes before comparison
Split(shouldTrimQuotes: false);

// split, trim quotes before comparison
Split(shouldTrimQuotes: true);
```

You might also play a bit and try to refactor the whole thing, trying to extract smaller general pieces of code into separate methods which might make it clearer what they are doing. This is one approach, for example:

```
// rewrites the specified file, removing all lines matched by the predicate
public static void RemoveLinesFromFile(string filename, Func<string, bool> match)
{
    var linesToKeep = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
        .Where(line => match(line))
        .ToList();

    File.WriteAllLines(filename, linesToKeep);
}

// gets the list of "delete codes" from the specified ini file
public IList<string> GetDeleteCodeList(string iniPath)
{
    return File.ReadLines(iniPath)
        .SkipWhile(l => l.Trim() != "[DELETE]")
        .Skip(1).ToList();
}

// removes lines from a tab-delimited file, where the specified listOfCodes contains
// at least one of the tokens inside that line
public static void RemoveLinesUsingCodeList(
    string filename,
    IList<string> listOfCodes,
    bool shouldTrimQuotes)
{
    RemoveLinesFromFile(filename, line =>
    {
        IEnumerable<string> tokens = line.Split('\t');               
        if (shouldTrimQuotes)
        {
            tokens = tokens.Select(v => v.Trim(' ', '"'));
        }
        return (tokens.Any(t => listOfCodes.Any(t.Equals)));
    });
}
```

Comment: I think no parameter is necessary. Double quote is not a valid symbol in a file name. You can just always trim your input.

Comment: @Neolisk: I don't think these values are necessary file names. OP is parsing a tab-delimited file, but only wants to trim quotes in some cases.

Comment: @Groo could you please tell me how to add the parameter. i am really new to this.. also i am getting an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast? in the line `value = value.Select(v => v.Trim(' ', '"'));`

Comment: @stacy: yes, sorry, type of the `value` variable should be explicitly set to `IEnumerable<string>`, otherwise the compiler will use `string[]` because of the `var` keyword.

Comment: so how can i use this in my function that's what i am wondering

Comment: @stacy: delete the first of these methods, and modify the second one to have the input parameter and the `if` clause. You end up with a single method which behaves differently based on its input parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67433/discussion-between-stacy-keb-and-groo).

Comment: @Groo once when i gave `Split(shouldTrimQuotes: false);`. its says the split does not contained in the context